# How to get browser to prompt to open or save an ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a link in an email which looks like this:

```
 ...DownloadReport?id=1
```

This first redirects to a login page where the user logs in.  On login success, I run this JavaScript to return the actual report:

```
function getReport() {
        $.ajax({ url: "/PropertySearch/Order/GetReport" });
}
```

The response to this includes the report (it is a tif).  However, the browser does not pop up a "Would you like to open or save this document?"

How do I get the browser to recognize that the response is a document and thus prompt to open or save?

Comment: You stop using ajax, redirect to the report the regular way instead, and supply the proper headers, where you set the content disposition to "attachment" etc.

Comment: OK, that works.  Changed the body to ` window.location.href = "/PropertySearch/Order/GetReport";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need Ajax for this. Just an  link is enough if you set the `content-disposition` to `attachment` in the server side code. This way the parent page will just stay open, if that was your major concern (why would you unnecessarily have chosen Ajax for this otherwise?). Besides, there is no way to handle this nicely acynchronously. PDF is not character data. It's binary data. You can't do stuff like $(element).load(). You want to use completely new request for this.For that `<a href="pdfservlet/filename.pdf">pdf</a>` is perfectly suitable.